# Problem after configuring RBS on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, remote-blob-storage, rbs, blob

I have configured RBS on a SharePoint site on one of our clients and I am getting the following error whenever I upload a file to a document library:

﻿﻿The URL '' is invalid. May refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

And looking at the logs I found this other error:

No provider of type  found. Check the server configuration or install the provider on the client

I have done all the configuration with no errors and now I am completely stuck in this problem. I did some googling but every thing I found related to this problem was not sufficient. Hope anyone here can help me.

Furhter information:

I did the configuration based on this blog post: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tejasr/archive/2011/04/01/experience-of-configuring-remote-blob-storage-rbs-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

I'm using SQL 2014 Express installed locally. Default instance name. I downloaded the RBS.msi (x64) file of the SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack. The SharePoint installation is completely fresh and updated. Nothing else is running on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, we ended up setting up all the environment again. We removed the SharePoint instance and recreated from the ground.